# Installing Tachometer on bike

Tags: motorcycle, installation

I have 1997 model Kawasaki 4s champion (100cc 4 stroke bike). It have no tachometer . is it possible to install new tachometer on my bike. can anyone give some advise ?. thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can install an external tachometer that reads your wheel speed. There's [one on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049IFX56) for Kawasaki for $19USD.

Some clamp onto a spark plug wire, others are 2 piece, where one small piece clamps onto your wheel, and the other clamps onto a fork and measures the wheel RPM - but those are more for bicycles, not motorcycles (where you'd like engine RPM - not wheel RPM).

Good luck! You can find more articles and forum posts by [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=external+motorcycle+tachometer) "External Motorcycle Tachometer"

Comment: Welcome to the site. We prefer a more thorough answer than just "Google it" Please edit your question to include more detailed information and or recommendations

Comment: Sorry Larry - offered a Google string that would bring up results and articles related to it. My apologies, will edit to reflect a more detailed answer now.